# Percentage frequency of repetition of values in array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code in Java that analyses input data. It takes the data as integer array and outputs different manipulations of the data. In my code, i also need to add the frequency of repetition for each value (in percentage). I managed to write the code but output does not work. How can i fix my output?

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
            int repeatNumber = 1; 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { 
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {  
                    repeatNumber++; 
                } 
            } 
            System.out.println("Frequency of repetition for " +a[i]+ ": " +repeatNumber+ ", "+(float)(((float)repeatNumber / (float)size) * (float)100)+ "%. "); 
        }
```

For example my expected output for array = {1; 1; 2; 4}
Frequency of repetition for 1: 2, 50.0%.
Frequency of repetition for 2: 1, 25.0%.
Frequency of repetition for 4: 1, 25.0%.

But it outputs as :
Frequency of repetition for 1: 2, 50.0%.
Frequency of repetition for 1: 1, 25.0%.
Frequency of repetition for 2: 1, 25.0%.
Frequency of repetition for 4: 1, 25.0%.

Comment: Yes, i just skip one element since i set repearNumber as 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're not keeping track of numbers that you've already seen.

You could change this without using any additional memory by mutating the array like

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(a[i] != null) {
        int repeatNumber = 1; 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { 
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {  
                repeatNumber++; 
                a[j] = null;
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println("Frequency of repetition for " +a[i]+ ": " +repeatNumber+ ", "+(float)(((float)repeatNumber / (float)size) * (float)100)+ "%. "); 
    }
}
```

That said, if you don't have a memory constraint then this code would be better off re-written in O(n) using a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to keep track of the frequency.
Or, in a more functional manner that's easily parallelizable like `Stream.of(a).collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()))`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution (Not optimized)

First of all in the main loop we check if the current number is already being calculated using a list of already processed numbers.
Then for each number (the current one), we run a second loop to search for other occurences, we will always find (current numer), that means for each number we have in the main array of numbers, there is at least one occurence.

And we calculate the freq using ( number of occurences / number of elements in the array)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,1,2,4));
    List<Integer> numbersAlreadyProcessed = new ArrayList();
    int occurenceNumber = 0;
    for(Integer number : numbers){
      occurenceNumber = 0;
      if(!numbersAlreadyProcessed.contains(number)){
        numbersAlreadyProcessed.add(number);
        for(Integer otherNumber : numbers){
          if(number == otherNumber){
            occurenceNumber++;
          }  
        }
        System.out.println(number + " :: " + (float)(occurenceNumber)/numbers.size());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try and explain solutions using code as example rather than posting a code only answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
         if(a[i]>0){
            int repeatNumber = 1; 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { 
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {  
                      a[j]=a[j]*(-1);
                    repeatNumber++; 
                } 
            } 
            System.out.println("Frequency of repetition for " +a[i]+ ": " +repeatNumber+ ", "+(float)(((float)repeatNumber / (float)size) * (float)100)+ "%. "); 
           }
           }
```

I convert the visited item into a negative number so that you can skip the repeated numbers.

Comment: Good way of thinking! Except this would only work for positive input data, the algorithm would not work for negative input, i believe.